# Apache POI is extremely slow

Tags: java, excel, io, apache-poi

I have seen many questions online about Apache POI performance, but none of them is as slow as my case and none of their solutions works for me. I am using NetBeans 8.0.2, JDK 1.8 and POI-3.12-20150511. To read a 300 KB xls (with 3000 rows and a few columns), this line takes 10 seconds to run:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file); //this line takes 10 seconds
```

To read a larger one like a 1 MB xls, it could take more than one minutes to create the HSSFWorkbook.

I have tried to disable the POI log and increase the JVM memory by adding these parameters:

> -Dorg.apache.poi.util.POILogger=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog
>   -J-Xmx1024m

They do not help. My machine has 12 GB memory so memory should not be a problem.

I do not know if it is the problem of Apache POI or JVM. But I have imported the 3000 rows data into MySQL, and it takes 2 seconds to read the data from MySQL (versus 10 seconds from Excel).

Comment: Benchmark your code using a proper benchmark tool. From the looks of it you might increase performance by using a [BufferedStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html) to reduce IO overhead for reads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a network problem. The connection speed to the drive where the excel file is located is slow.